# Best practices for using sinon for nodeJS unit testing

Tags: node.js, mocking, sinon

I'm coming from Java experience with spring framework and looking for the most elegant way to write tests with mocks in nodejs.

For java its look like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class AccountManagerFacadeTest {

    @InjectMocks
    AccountManagerFacade accountManagerFacade;

    @Mock
    IService service

    @Test
    public void test() {
        //before
                   here you define specific mock behavior 
        //when

        //then
    }
}
```

Looking for something similar for nodeJS, any suggestions?

Comment: What exactly is your case? You listed an example for a class which is used in the framework that uses DI and was designed with testability in mind. But in JS you don't necessarily use classes. And even if you do, `@` decorators aren't supported natively. And even if they would, you need to write code with this testability style in mind.

Comment: True, my goal is to achieve the best practices with writing nodeJS code that would be easy to test and would be readable as well :)

Comment: The question is too broad at this point. It's hard task to describe best practices in the form of the answer, that's why 'best practice' questions are off-topic on SO. You need to get your hands dirty to know the nuances of writing testable code. Sinon isn't used like you showed because of reasons I mentioned. There are other things like https://github.com/florinn/typemoq that are specific to OOP and TS. FWIW, Sinon doesn't do module mocking which is needed in Node, you will need other libs for that. Jest is more feature-full in this respect, it's capable of mocking both functions and modules.

Comment: Thank you, will try this out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mocking with node.js is much easier than Java thanks to javascript flexibility.

Here is a full example of class mocking, with the following class:

```
// lib/accountManager.js
class AccountManager {
  create (name) {
    this._privateCreate(name);
  }

  update () {
    console.log('update')
  }

  delete () {
    console.log('delete')
  }

  _privateCreate() {
    console.log('_privateCreate')
  }
}

module.exports = AccountManager
```

You could mock it like this:

```
// test/accountManager.test.js
const
  sinon = require('sinon'),
  should = require('should')
  AccountManager = require('../lib/accountManager');

require('should-sinon'); // Required to use sinon helpers with should

describe('AccountManager', () => {
  let
    accountManager,
    accountManagerMock;

  beforeEach(() => {
    accountManagerMock = {
      _privateCreate: sinon.stub() // Mock only desired methods
    };

    accountManager = Object.assign(new AccountManager(), accountManagerMock);
  });

  describe('#create', () => {
    it('call _privateCreate method with good arguments', () => {
      accountManager.create('aschen');

      should(accountManagerMock._privateCreate).be.calledOnce();
      should(accountManagerMock._privateCreate).be.calledWith('aschen');
    })
  });
});
```

Here you can find more example on mocking classes and dependencies: https://github.com/Aschen/workshop-tdd/blob/master/step2/test/file.test.js